# Откуда не возьмись появился горизонтальный скрол

Tags: css, html

Не одно изображение не выходит за рамки контента, при этом js код показал что выходит каждый элемент, что это такое?!?!? Раньше подобного небыло, и при удаление всех блоков, кроме одного, скрол все равно есть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мы по скринам догадаться должны что у вас там в коде?, по вашим скринам лишь очевидно что у вас содержимое не помещается в контейнер и выходит за его пределы

Comment: Просто добавь контейнеру `overflow:hidden`

Answer (score 0):

Можно посмотреть во вкладке elements, там будут элементы дерева DOM. Возможно у одного элемента задана ширина больше экрана. Нужно смотреть стили каждого элемента.